# HDMI: connecting shield with ground

Tags: hdmi

I am working on a project with HDMI.
I use an HDMI in and HDMI connector where i connected thru the data lines, but i want to ground the shields (TMDS shield 0, 1, 2).
Will i need a decoupling capacitors ? And how do i calculate them.

Thank you